# Getting hibernate to log clob parameters

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

*(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53316/hibernate-crops-clob-values-oddly) for the problem I'm trying to solve)*

How do you get hibernate to log clob values it's going to insert. It is logging other value types, such as Integer etc.

I have the following in my log4j config:

```
log4j.logger.net.sf.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.net.sf.hibernate.type=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=DEBUG
```

Which produces output such as:

```
(org.hibernate.SQL) insert into NoteSubstitutions (note, listIndex, substitution) values (?, ?, ?)
(org.hibernate.type.LongType) binding '170650' to parameter: 1
(org.hibernate.type.IntegerType) binding '0' to parameter: 2
(org.hibernate.SQL) insert into NoteSubstitutions (note, listIndex, substitution) values (?, ?, ?)
(org.hibernate.type.LongType) binding '170650' to parameter: 1
(org.hibernate.type.IntegerType) binding '1' to parameter: 2
```

However you'll note that it never displays `parameter: 3` which is our clob.

What I would really want is something like:

```
(org.hibernate.SQL) insert into NoteSubstitutions (note, listIndex, substitution) values (?, ?, ?)
(org.hibernate.type.LongType) binding '170650' to parameter: 1
(org.hibernate.type.IntegerType) binding '0' to parameter: 2
(org.hibernate.type.ClobType) binding 'something' to parameter: 3
(org.hibernate.SQL) insert into NoteSubstitutions (note, listIndex, substitution) values (?, ?, ?)
(org.hibernate.type.LongType) binding '170650' to parameter: 1
(org.hibernate.type.IntegerType) binding '1' to parameter: 2
(org.hibernate.type.ClobType) binding 'something else' to parameter: 3
```

How do I get it to show this in the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
log4j.logger.net.sf.hibernate=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG
```

That's the finest level you'll get. If it does not show the information you want, then it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like you can't. *(Thanks [Marcio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53365/getting-hibernate-to-log-clob-parameters#53419) for the suggestion, but sadly that didn't add anything useful)*

Answer (score 0):

Try to set log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE and see if that helps.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't help either. I think it's just because you can't guarantee that a clob is dumpable to a console so it doesn't.